# How to write "é" and 6 thin dots (the opposite of "é") in braille with LaTeX

Tags: braille

I'm trying to write "é"  and 6 thin dots (the opposite of "é") in braille with LaTeX. Also, I would like to write those two character bigger. Could you help me? Thanks a lot.

That's my tex code:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[puttinydots]{braille}

\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mytable}[1]{%
\enskip\begin{tabular}[t]{r|l} 
\hline #1 \hline
\end{tabular}\enskip}

\newcommand{\mytablewith}[2]{%
\enskip\begin{tabular}[t]{r|l} 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1} \\
\hline #2 \hline
\end{tabular}\enskip}

\newcommand{\mytaglist}[1]{%
\enskip\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
#1
\end{tabular}\enskip}


\begin{document}


\section{Braille Alphabets}

{\Huge { \braille{é}\braille{ }}}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, characters are encoded differently in different languages. See [French Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_–_lettres_diacritées_et_ligatures_propres_à_diverses_langues_étrangères)

Answer (score 0):

The length `\brailleunit` stores the size of the Braille dots, and you can change it with `\setlength`. However, since the tinydots are implemented using `\tiny.`, they don't scale with `\brailleunit` length.

The following MWE changes the size of brailledots and implements the character `é` with 2346 positions. You can further define new characters using `\def@char` between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[puttinydots]{braille}

\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
    \def@char{é}{2346}
\makeatother

\setlength{\brailleunit}{4mm} % Default is 2mm

\begin{document}
    
\section{Braille Alphabets}
\braille{e}\braille{é}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I add a picture in order to help you about my idea of output.

Comment: I don't know Braille, but my answer is complete as you can set `\def@char{é}{123456}` instead